# getValue() from second order ui.Select in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like two make two `ui.Select` widgets. The items of second `ui.Select` depends on first `ui.Select`. Then I would like to get values of both `ui.Select`s using `ui.Button`. I have drafted a code, but it does not work as I want. When I click the button, it gets the value of first `ui.Select` and prints it, but ignores the second `ui.Select`'s value. Is anyone can help me improve the code and give an suggest how can I make it?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1796c9feaca7638dc195f52850bca64c

```
var panel = ui.Panel();
panel.style().set({width: '200px', position: 'bottom-right'});
ui.root.add(panel);

var firstname_select = ui.Select({
  items: [{label:'AAA', value:'AAA'}, {label:'BBB', value:'BBB'}, {label:'CCC', value:'CCC'}],
  onChange: function() {

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'AAA'){
      var secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'A1', value:'A1'}, {label:'A2', value:'A2'}, {label:'A3', value:'A3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'BBB'){
      var secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'B1', value:'B1'}, {label:'B2', value:'B2'}, {label:'B3', value:'B3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'CCC'){
      var secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'C1', value:'C1'}, {label:'C2', value:'C2'}, {label:'C3', value:'C3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }    
    panel.widgets().set(1, secondname_select);
  }

  });

var getvalue = ui.Button({
  label: 'Get Values',
  onClick: function() {
    print('First: ' + firstname_select.getValue());
    print('Select: ' + secondname_select.getValue());
  }
});

var secondname_select = ui.Select();
panel.widgets().set(1, firstname_select);
panel.widgets().set(2, secondname_select);
panel.widgets().set(3, getvalue);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `secondname_select` the button uses to extract the value always point to your initial, empty, `ui.Select` instance. When `firstname_select` change, you create a local variable, also named `secondname_select`. The button still see the initial, empty, instance. To solve this, you can reassign the initial `secondname_select` by just removing the `var` keyword in your `firstname_select` change callback.

```
var panel = ui.Panel();
panel.style().set({width: '200px', position: 'bottom-right'});
ui.root.add(panel);


var firstname_select = ui.Select({
  items: [{label:'AAA', value:'AAA'}, {label:'BBB', value:'BBB'}, {label:'CCC', value:'CCC'}],
  onChange: function() {

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'AAA'){
      secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'A1', value:'A1'}, {label:'A2', value:'A2'}, {label:'A3', value:'A3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'BBB'){
      secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'B1', value:'B1'}, {label:'B2', value:'B2'}, {label:'B3', value:'B3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }

    if (firstname_select.getValue() === 'CCC'){
      secondname_select = ui.Select({
        items: [
        {label:'C1', value:'C1'}, {label:'C2', value:'C2'}, {label:'C3', value:'C3'}],
        onChange: function() {
        }
      });
    }    
    panel.widgets().set(1, secondname_select);
  }

  });


var getvalue = ui.Button({
  label: 'Get Values',
  onClick: function() {
    print('First: ' + firstname_select.getValue());
    print('Select: ' + secondname_select.getValue());
  }
});

var secondname_select = ui.Select();
panel.widgets().set(1, firstname_select);
panel.widgets().set(2, secondname_select);
panel.widgets().set(3, getvalue);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3c2ea0753457c7a7bd18ca650f5404ae

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that there are 2 `ui.Select` widgets named `secondname_select` in your code. First one you defined globally as `panel.widgets().set(2, secondname_select);`, which is empty. And a second one is created on the fly inside your function as `panel.widgets().set(1, secondname_select);`

Then `onClick` event of your `getValue` button queries the first `secondname_select` that is empty.

One possible way to fix it is to query the right one:

```
var getvalue = ui.Button({
  label: 'Get Values',
  onClick: function() {
    print('First: ' + firstname_select.getValue());
    print('Second: ' + panel.widgets().get(1).getValue());
  }
});
```

Comment: [panel.widgets(...).get(...).getValue is not a function], I received such error for this query

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the widget index. Fixed it. Also, [here's the code on EE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7ff17bdda40db4a8ccf09b2f3683f99e)